# wxPython - wx.StaticText not aligning properly

Tags: python, wxpython, alignment, wxwidgets

[image]

As you can see, none of those `wx.StaticText` items align properly when it starts, once you try to resize the window, then it's all working.

Sample code:

```
self.CodeTitleStaticText = wx.StaticText(id=wxID_MAINFRAMECODETITLESTATICTEXT,
              label=u'Code', name=u'CodeTitleStaticText', parent=self.MainPanel,
              pos=wx.Point(10, 10), size=wx.Size(80, 20),
              style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
```

Then I put all these `wx.StaticText` items into a `wx.GridBagSizer`.
Could anybody explain to me in which part did I mess it up?

**I'm running win 7 64bit with Python 2.7.3(32bit) and wxPython 2.8.12.1**

Comment: did you do a `Layout()` or `Refresh()` after adding those items?

Comment: Nice animated screenie in the question! :)

Comment: @CorleyBrigman: Yes I've tried both but they didn't work. At first I thought it should work if you force the UI to redraw/refresh, so I did a little search but had no luck with `Layout()` or `Refresh`.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman: `Layout()` finally worked! Only you have to use it on `self.MainPanel`, thanks!

Comment: @Shane: could you post this as an answer and accept it.  Especially after being mesmerized by the graphic, it took me a long time to realize this question was answered hours ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution.

Some of you may have tried `Layout()` and found it didn't work, well the problem is, you have to **redraw/refresh that specific panel** on which the sizers are attached to, it won't work if you just update the frame.

I fixed both of my `MainPanel` and `StatusBar` alignment problem by implement `Layout()` on separate panels. Although I don't know why it doesn't work on main frame, maybe somebody can add more explanation to this?